# Sending .py -> .html value to .js (Django, Mapbox)

Tags: javascript, html, django, mapbox

Below is my code in my main.html file:

```
<body>
  <h1>mappymappy</h1>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '{{ mapbox_access_token }}'
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-73.9911, 40.7051],
      zoom: 9.5
    })
  </script>

  {% for center in drop_in_centers %}
  <script>
    new mapboxgl.Marker({ "color": 'red' })
      .setLngLat([{{ center.longitude }}, {{ center.latitude }}])
      .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
      .setHTML("<h2>Drop-in Center</h2><h3>{{center.center_name}}</h3>"))
      .addTo(map)
  </script>
  {% endfor %}
```

I want to move the scripts to a separate .js file.
However, in order to do that I have to figure out a way to

1. send the values `mapbox_access_token` and `drop_in_centers` to .js file
2. and make the values able to be used in the .js file.

How can I do this?

+) both `mapbox_access_token` and `drop_in_centers` are from views.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1) define vars in the template, pass them to js

views.py:

```
def my_view_function(request):
   
    # define variables: 
    map_box_token = 'the_token'
    drop_in_centers = 'the_drop_ins'

    # pack context:
    context = {
        'map_box_token' : map_box_token,
        'drop_in_centers' : drop_in_centers,
    }

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

template.html:

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    var map_box_token='{{map_box_token}}';
    var drop_in_centers='{{drop_in_centers}}';
  </script>
  <!-- include script.js after vars are defined -->
  <script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script> 
</body>
```

script.js:

```
console.log(map_box_token) // ex: use as needed
console.log(drop_in_centers) // ex: use as needed
```

Option 2) use ajax to retrieve data from views.py

views.py:

```
def my_view_function(request):
   
    # define variables: 
    map_box_token = 'the_token'
    drop_in_centers = 'the_drop_ins'

    # pack context:
    context = json.dumps({
        'map_box_token' : map_box_token,
        'drop_in_centers' : drop_in_centers,
    })

    return HttpResponse(context)
```

script.js:

```
function get_vars() {

  // conduct ajax request:
  $.ajax({
    url : 'the_url',
    success : get_vars_success, // reference to function below:
  })

} $(document).ready(get_vars) // or call as needed

function get_vars_success(response) {
  
  // unpack context:
  var map_box_token = response.map_box_token;
  var drop_in_centers = response.drop_in_centers;
  
  // use as needed:
  ...

}
```

Comment: I would add defaults to the js declarations for the templates in option 1, but this is the solution... Also note if pure JS is what is wanted, it has to be the Ajax call.